# beep-evdev - Beep the PC speaker on Linux using evdev

Tags: rust

**Updated question on 2023-08-31 with extended codebase, since so answers were posted yet.**

## Background

I am rewriting a program in Rust, which needs to be able to beep the PC speaker.
I am using a udev rule to grant a user in the group `beep` access to the speaker, which works fine with [`beep`](https://github.com/spkr-beep/beep).

However, I did not want to invoke the `beep` command via a subprocess, as I did with an earlier Python version of this program.

So I had a look at [`beep`](https://crates.io/crates/beep), which did not work for me, as it uses `/dev/console` and at [`pc-beeper`](https://crates.io/crates/pc-beeper), which always segfaults on my machine.

Hence, I tried to figure out, how the original beep works on my system:

```
$ beep --debug
beep: Verbose: evdev: driver_detect 0x55a1093d60c0 (nil)
beep: Verbose: lib: opened /dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr as fd=3
beep: Verbose: main: using evdev driver (fd=3, dev=/dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr)
beep: Verbose: main: 1 times 200 ms beeps (100 ms delay between, 0 ms delay after) @ 440 Hz
beep: Verbose: evdev: driver_begin_tone 0x55a1093d60c0 440
beep: Verbose: evdev: driver_end_tone 0x55a1093d60c0
beep: Verbose: evdev: driver_end_tone 0x55a1093d60c0
beep: Verbose: evdev: driver_fini 0x55a1093d60c0
```

... and saw that it was using `evdev`.

## Solution

Hence I re-implemented an `evdev`-based `beep` library:

`src/lib.rs`

````rust
use evdev::{Device, EventType, InputEvent, SoundType};
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;

#[cfg(feature = "serde")]
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

pub const DEFAULT_DELAY: Duration = Duration::from_millis(100);
pub const DEFAULT_FREQ: u16 = 440;
pub const DEFAULT_LEN: Duration = Duration::from_millis(200);
pub const DEFAULT_REPEATS: u16 = 1;
const FILE: &str = "/dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr";

/// A sequence of notes
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "serde", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
pub struct Melody(Vec<Note>);

impl Melody {
    #[must_use]
    pub fn new(notes: Vec<Note>) -> Self {
        Self(notes)
    }

    /// Plays the melody
    ///
    /// # Examples
    /// ```
    /// use beep_evdev::Melody;
    ///
    /// let melody: Melody = vec![
    ///     (659, 120).into(),
    ///     (622, 120).into(),
    ///     (659, 120).into(),
    ///     (622, 120).into(),
    ///     (659, 120).into(),
    ///     (94, 120).into(),
    ///     (587, 120).into(),
    ///     (523, 120).into(),
    ///     (440, 120).into(),
    ///     (262, 120).into(),
    ///     (330, 120).into(),
    ///     (440, 120).into(),
    ///     (494, 120).into(),
    ///     (330, 120).into(),
    ///     (415, 120).into(),
    ///     (494, 120).into(),
    ///     (523, 120).into(),
    ///     (330, 120).into(),
    ///     (659, 120).into(),
    ///     (622, 120).into(),
    ///     (659, 120).into(),
    ///     (622, 120).into(),
    ///     (659, 120).into(),
    ///     (494, 120).into(),
    ///     (587, 120).into(),
    ///     (523, 120).into(),
    ///     (440, 120).into(),
    ///     (262, 120).into(),
    ///     (330, 120).into(),
    ///     (440, 120).into(),
    ///     (494, 120).into(),
    ///     (330, 120).into(),
    ///     (523, 120).into(),
    ///     (494, 120).into(),
    ///     (440, 120).into(),
    /// ]
    /// .into();
    /// melody.play().expect("could not play melody :-(");
    /// ```
    ///
    /// # Errors
    /// Returns an [`std::io::Error`] on I/O errors
    pub fn play(&self) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
        for note in &self.0 {
            note.play()?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}

impl Default for Melody {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new(vec![Note::default()])
    }
}

impl From<Vec<Note>> for Melody {
    fn from(notes: Vec<Note>) -> Self {
        Self::new(notes)
    }
}

impl From<&[Note]> for Melody {
    fn from(notes: &[Note]) -> Self {
        Self::new(Vec::from(notes))
    }
}

/// A note of a certain frequency and duration
/// that may be repeated with a delay
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "serde", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
pub struct Note {
    frequency: u16,
    length: Duration,
    repeats: u16,
    delay: Duration,
}

impl Note {
    /// Creates a new note
    /// # Attributes
    /// * frequency - The frequency in Hertz
    /// * length -  The length of the note
    /// * repeats - The amount of repeats
    /// * delay - The delay before each repeat
    #[must_use]
    pub const fn new(frequency: u16, length: Duration, repeats: u16, delay: Duration) -> Self {
        Self {
            frequency,
            length,
            repeats,
            delay,
        }
    }

    /// Plays the note
    ///
    /// # Examples
    /// ```
    /// use beep_evdev::Note;
    ///
    /// Note::default().play().expect("could not play melody :-(");
    /// ```
    ///
    /// # Errors
    /// Returns an [`std::io::Error`] on I/O errors
    pub fn play(&self) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
        if self.repeats > 0 {
            beep(self.frequency)?;
            sleep(self.length);
            beep(0)?;
        }

        for _ in 1..self.repeats {
            sleep(self.delay);
            beep(self.frequency)?;
            sleep(self.length);
            beep(0)?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}

impl Default for Note {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new(DEFAULT_FREQ, DEFAULT_LEN, DEFAULT_REPEATS, DEFAULT_DELAY)
    }
}

impl From<(u16, u64)> for Note {
    /// Creates a note from a `(frequency, length)` tuple with default repeats and delay
    fn from((frequency, length): (u16, u64)) -> Self {
        Self::from((frequency, Duration::from_millis(length)))
    }
}

impl From<(u16, Duration)> for Note {
    /// Creates a note from a `(frequency, length)` tuple with default repeats and delay
    fn from((frequency, length): (u16, Duration)) -> Self {
        Self::new(frequency, length, DEFAULT_REPEATS, DEFAULT_DELAY)
    }
}

/// Beeps the PC speaker at the given frequency
///
/// # Examples
/// ```
/// use beep_evdev::beep;
/// use std::{thread, time};
///
/// beep(440).expect("could not beep");
/// thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(500));
/// beep(880).expect("could not beep");
/// thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(500));
/// beep(0).expect("could not beep");
/// ```
///
/// # Errors
/// Returns [`std::io::Error`] on I/O errors
pub fn beep(hertz: u16) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    Device::open(FILE)?.send_events(&[InputEvent::new(
        EventType::SOUND,
        SoundType::SND_TONE.0,
        i32::from(hertz),
    )])
}
````

`Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "beep-evdev"
authors = ["Richard Neumann <mail@richard-neumann.de>"]
description = "Beep the PC speaker using evdev"
license = "MIT"
homepage = "https://github.com/conqp/beep-evdev/"
repository = "https://github.com/conqp/beep-evdev/"
readme = "README.md"
documentation = "https://docs.rs/beep-evdev"
keywords = [ "beep", "pcspkr", "evdev"]
version = "0.3.2"
edition = "2021"
exclude = [
    ".gitignore",
]

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
evdev = "0.12.1"
serde = { version = "1.0.166", features = ["derive"], optional = true }

[features]
serde = ["dep:serde"]
```

Do you have any thoughts on this?
Did I re-invent the wheel?